# lua send mail with gmail account

Tags: email, lua

I want to send email with my gmail account, I gave it a try, but no luck, so  is anyone can give me a sample? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

I used lualogging api,  the code is

```
require"logging.email"

logger = logging.email {
  rcpt = "aaa@sina.com",
  from = "bbb@gmail.com",
  user = "bbb@gmail.com",
  password = *****,
  server = "smtp.gmail.com",
  port = 587,
  headers = { 
    rcpt = "aaa@sina.com",
    from = "bbb@gmail.com", 
    subject = "[%level] logging.email test", 
  },
}

logger:error("error!")
```

Comment: would luv some codes. :)

Comment: you really need to work on your question a bit more if you want to get any sort of useful answer. Specify things like your current setup (PC? Mobile? Corona SDK, maybe?). Also take the time to actually explain (with details, and code) what you have tried.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should look at [LuaSocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/), especially its [SMTP module](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/smtp.html) which can be used to send mail using your GMail account. You also need a SSL library, I use [LuaSec](https://github.com/brunoos/luasec) which was designed to be used together with LuaSocket. This is the code I successfully used to send emails using my GMail account:

```
-- Michal Kottman, 2011, public domain
local socket = require 'socket'
local smtp = require 'socket.smtp'
local ssl = require 'ssl'
local https = require 'ssl.https'
local ltn12 = require 'ltn12'

function sslCreate()
    local sock = socket.tcp()
    return setmetatable({
        connect = function(_, host, port)
            local r, e = sock:connect(host, port)
            if not r then return r, e end
            sock = ssl.wrap(sock, {mode='client', protocol='tlsv1'})
            return sock:dohandshake()
        end
    }, {
        __index = function(t,n)
            return function(_, ...)
                return sock[n](sock, ...)
            end
        end
    })
end

function sendMessage(subject, body)
    local msg = {
        headers = {
            to = 'Your Target <target email>',
            subject = subject
        },
        body = body
    }

    local ok, err = smtp.send {
        from = '<your email>',
        rcpt = '<target email>',
        source = smtp.message(msg),
        user = 'username',
        password = 'password',
        server = 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port = 465,
        create = sslCreate
    }
    if not ok then
        print("Mail send failed", err) -- better error handling required
    end
end
```

Comment: Is Lua dont support Mail servers requiring authentication (acts weird and does not support SSL) ?

Comment: In the example there already is authentication and encryption. See the `user` and `password` fields and the `sslCreate` function used to initiate the connection. You just need the LuaSocket and LuaSec libraries.

Comment: I had a try , it works !  Thanks very much. And now I want to use another mail service , When I tried that I get 1 error messages that say: "Mail send failed wrong version number", what should  I do ? modify the sslCreate function?

Comment: And if a smtp server isn't need to establesh the secure connection, but need to authentication. what the code like? thanks. Sorry, ask you so much, I'm a newbie , so :)

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know your alternate mail service setup, so it may require other SSL version, like [`protocol = 'sslv3'`](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~brunoos/luasec/reference.html). If you do not need SSL at all, remove the `create = sslCreate` line.

Comment: No matter how, Thanks for the comments, guys!

Answer (score 0):

The code from Michal Kottman works properly but it fails (for me) when smpt server works on 587 port, using a pretty different way to accept mail to send (according wo what I read). Does anybody faced anything similar? I always obtain "wrong version number" on server working on port 587.