# sending mail via Outlook to lua

Tags: lua

I send my emails via gmail. It works perfectly. How do I change the server setting so I can send an email through Outlook?

these are the settings for gmail

```
local ok, err = smtp.send {
    from = '<>',
    rcpt = too,
    source = smtp.message(msg),
    user = us,
    password = pswrd,
    server = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port = 465, 
    create = sslCreate
}
```

if i write

```
local ok, err = smtp.send {
    from = '<>',
    rcpt = too,
    source = smtp.message(msg),
    user = us,
    password = pswrd,
    server = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
    port = 587, 
    create = sslCreate

}
```

it does not work for Outlook

How to fix it?

Comment: What's in `err`?

Comment: variable to record the error if it exists. I think the code problem is in line 
create = sslCreate , 
but I don't know what parameter to put

Comment: yes, I know what it's *for*, but what does it *contain*?

Comment: If I run the script with the data above , 

wrong version number

Comment: I would go look for help on outlook.com, and see what requirements there are to make a connection.

Comment: Also, what module is providing `smtp`, and what is `sslCreate`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm new and poorly versed in this topic :(
The code I use is an example from this site http://qaru.site/questions/777429/lua-send-mail-with-gmail-account
I think ssl is an encryption Protocol used in Google. 
Outlook uses the report STARTTLS, but I don't know how to describe it to the `created` field in Lua( 

The smtp namespace provides functionality to send e-mail messages. 
http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/smtp.html

I apologize for my stupidity :)

Comment: This problem has already been described in the comments to the post above, but it has not been solved (
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070623/lua-send-mail-with-gmail-account/45150515#45150515